# MySQL SELECT use 2 newly created "coloumns" in a third

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    *,
    (SELECT locked FROM forum_topics t WHERE t.id = topicid) as topiclocked,
    forum_subtopics.locked as stlocked
FROM forum_subtopics
WHERE topicid = 1;
```

I would like to use the fields `topiclocked` and `stlocked` to create a third custom coloumn named `locked`. I tried the following, but MySQL told me that `topiclocked` does not exist:

```
SELECT
    *,
    (SELECT locked FROM forum_topics t WHERE t.id = topicid) as topiclocked,
    forum_subtopics.locked as stlocked,
    (topiclocked || stlocked) as locked
FROM forum_subtopics
WHERE topicid = 1;
```

> Unknown column 'topiclocked' in 'field list'

How can I create that third coloumn in a way that it actually works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign variables in the `select`-part, like this

```
SELECT
    *,
    @topiclocked:=(SELECT locked FROM forum_topics t WHERE t.id = topicid) as topiclocked,
    @stlocked:=forum_subtopics.locked as stlocked,
    (@topiclocked || @stlocked) as locked
FROM forum_subtopics
WHERE topicid = 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/572453/1

I would rewrite that query with a `JOIN` instead, that way you don't have to do a *subquery* and you'll have `locked` from both tables available.

```
SELECT s.*,
    t.locked as topiclocked,
    s.locked as stlocked,
    (t.locked || s.locked) as locked
FROM forum_subtopics s
JOIN forum_topics t on (s.topicid = t.id)
WHERE topicid = 1;
```

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid. I tried doing this too, but without the colons in front of the `=` signs. Thank you!

Comment: I recommend using := everywhere, in the select-part it's needed cause = means just "return true of both parts are equal". In stored procedures both = and := works for variable assignments but sticking to := is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `alias name (topiclocked)` in the same `select` statement. Make the query as `sub-select` and do the concatenation in `outer query`. Try this.

```
SELECT *,
       ( topiclocked || stlocked ) AS locked
FROM   (SELECT *,
               (SELECT locked
                FROM   forum_topics t
                WHERE  t.id = topicid) AS topiclocked,
               forum_subtopics.locked  AS stlocked
        FROM   forum_subtopics
        WHERE  topicid = 1) a;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alias defined in a `select` cannot be used in that `select` or `where` clause.  Typically, you would use a subquery or common table expression (but not in MySQL) to get around this.  However, MySQL materializes subqueries, so this has an impact on performance.

In your case, you could rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT s.*, t.locked as topiclocked, s.locked as stlocked,
       (t.locked || s.locked) as locked
FROM forum_subtopics s JOIN
     forum_topics t
     ON t.id = s.topicid
WHERE s.topicid = 1;
```

You might need a `left join` if you have subtopics with no topic.  I am guessing that is not the case in your data, so I'm just using an inner join.